# PHP : How to wait for a file written by an external script to exist

Tags: php, bash

I'm working on a simple PHP based website

The basic structure is :

- It takes some data as input via a web form, hands it over to some
  shell scripts to process (via the system() function)
- The result of the processing is written to a .txt file
- This file is then read by the script and displayed in the browser

It takes about 2-3 seconds to generate the .txt file after the handover is completed

Is there any correct way of making PHP wait for the file to be generated?

Currently I put the PHP script to sleep for 5 seconds and then read the file exists. This is obviously not a very good idea since each time the PHP script executes, it will take 5 seconds regardless of the time actually needed.

Runs on Apache on Ubuntu if thats relevant

Comment: I thought `system()` _does_ wait until the child process completes.

Comment: @Izkata from the PHP manual `If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.`  . In my case the output is redirected to a file

Comment: So why cant you just have PHP hang until the file is created?  Shell out to the scripts, and when they are dune the PHP script will resume.

Comment: I need the output redirected to the text file

Comment: Are you redirecting the output, or creating the file in the script?  If the latter, then there's no problem, just use system and your php script will return when your shell scripts finish.  If you are redirecting the output of the system call, then dont do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer:  Don't use `system()`, use [exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) without redirecting to a file:

```
$foo = array();
exec('ls', $foo);
$output = implode("\n", $foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to throw a Javascript ajax call on the page that runs every couple seconds looking for the updated file.  Once its found the loop stops and the page refreshes.

Comment: This requires extra storage of some sort, so you don't start polling for another user's data, with some sort of unique ID to pass between the javascript and PHP (or use PHP sessions), that's associated with the output file...  The scripts are only supposed to last a couple seconds anyway, so I'd call this overkill.